# Cannot read property 'fromProject' of undefined – What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular7

**EDIT - Solution**
`npm update` (of all things I tried I forgot that one) solved my issue. I hope i can help anyone else that stumbles upon this problem.

**Original problem:**

After doing some changes I tried `ng serve` and all of a sudden this shows up (see code below)

So I did some changes yes, but now all that is commented out, it should run now just like it did yesterday. But for some reason it doesn't.

```
To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
/Users/fs/repos/user_port_dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:10
const config = config_1.CliConfig.fromProject() || config_1.CliConfig.fromGlobal();
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromProject' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fs/repos/user_port_dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:10:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at loadCommands (/Users/fs/repos/user_port_dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:8:18)
    at default_1 (/Users/fs/repos/user_port_dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:37:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js:125:1)
```

Right now, I just want to be able to `ng serve` and see that all works again and work my way from there.

I tried `npm cache clean` although not --force, that didn't affect anything.

Anyone have a clue what's wrong?

Comment: Try to do a clean installation of nodeJS, remove `node_modules` folder and then do a `npm i`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi removing nodeJS requires the removal of brew aswell right?

Comment: Mh, I don't know but since (I believe) this error si caused only by the CLI, you can try to not remove brew

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I'm sorry to waste your time, I thought I tried everything and last thing I did before removing was npm update, and that solved it. I will see if I can remove this post, otherwise I will probably get lots of downvotes now for wasting peoples time. I apologize for wasting your time, I usually try everything but now I failed.

Comment: Don't remove the question, it could be usefull to someone else! Just edit your adding how you solve this :)